# Получить элемента массива срезом, даже если диапазон выходит за него

Tags: массивы, swift, срез

Возможно ли получить элементы масива срезом, если диапазон выходит за пределы?
Например

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4]
print(array[3...100])
```

Можно ли как-то получить [3,4]?
Как бы, только ту часть, которая попадает в диапазон.
P.S.
В Python можно просто сделать array[3:100] и получить элементы, которые попали в этот диапазон, без ошибок. Может в swift есть аналог?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете написать свой extension для Ваших потребностей.

В примере вместо range для subscript используем tuple для простоты:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(safe borders: (begin: Int, end: Int)) -> ArraySlice<Element> {
        assert(borders.begin <= borders.end) // Дабы исключить возможную ошибку
        guard let firstIndice = indices.first, let lastIndice = indices.last else {
            return [] 
        } // Значит пустой массив, раз нет indices.
        return self[Swift.max(borders.begin, firstIndice)...Swift.min(borders.end, lastIndice)]
    }
}
```

И применение:

```
let someArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(someArr[safe: (3, 100)]) // -> prints [3, 4]
```